# Can I write to the console log to debug a web application with C#

Tags: c#

I would like to log some variables in my ASP MVC3 application while I debug. I tried some different things such as:

```
Debug.Log(topTitle + " " + subTitle);
```

This doesn't seem to work.  How can I write to the console of VS2010 from my C# code?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

To write to Console Window in Visual studio use:

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(topTitle + " " + subTitle);
```

Below is the screenshot of its working:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Debug](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debug.aspx) class to emit debugging information from you application. You can even add [trace listener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y5y10s7.aspx) to your `web.config` file to redirect the output to a file or event log when you're not debugging from Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

To write to Console Window in Visual studio use:

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(topTitle + " " + subTitle);
```

or you can view and manipulate with `Immediate window`. [Immediate window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f177hahy.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

`System.Diagnostics.Debug` does not have log method. You can use `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine`  . You can view output in output window . Then make sure that you are running under debug mode.

. Debug information is only visible when you are running in Debug mode. In Release mode  Debug statements will not visible 
(you can use Trace instead of Debug if you want these statements to be visible in Release mode).

Please refer the following article

[How to trace and debug in Visual C#](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815788)

Answer (score 0):

If you are running a dotnet project on visual studio code terminal, use the syntax `System.Console.WriteLine("Something")`.

Cheers!